# Where does VM derive code for $file_list?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

Can someone tell me where the code for `$file_list` is sourced in Virtuemart? To be specific, in the **flypage.tpl.php** file, there is a snippet of code that looks like this:

```
<span style="font-style: italic;">
  <?php echo $file_list ?>
</span>
```

This code generates the HTML for files that have been linked to the product. Unfortunately, the formatting of that section is pretty ugly by default and I'm trying to figure out how to modify the source. Can't find it to save my soul. It doesn't appear to be anywhere in the template files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be here:
administrator/com_virtuemart\classes\ps_product_files.php

and search for function get_file_list

Right under this function (row 622 - 626) should be html template for product files.

Also hate this non MVC architecture. Looking forward to VM 2.0

Comment: Wow... I honestly don't think I ever would have found it without help. Yep, that did the trick, and I thank you much more than Stack Overflow's +1 and "checkbox for correct answer" can ever communicate.